# What is the order of connecting modules in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I have an express application with mongodb. And it's some structure:

```sh
├── main.js
└── src
    ├── controllers
    │   └── auth.controller.js
    ├── models
    │   └── user.model.js
    ├── services
        └── crypto.service.js
```

In `user.model.js` I have a schema which required a cryptoService `crypto.service.js`:

```
const cryptoService = require('../services/crypro.service');
```

It's work ok and `user.model.js` has connecting faster then `auth.controller.js`

And I have as well `index.js` file in a `service` folder and it looks like:

```
exports.cryptoService = require('./crypro.service');
```

But if I use the destructuring in `user.model.js`:

```
const { cryptoService } = require('../services');
```

then I get a problem and `auth.controller.js` has connecting faster then `user.model.js`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are battling a circular dependency, but it's not entirely clear how all of your dependencies look like and what problem exactly you are getting by importing `services/index.js` instead of `services/crypto.service.js`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your comment. Oh, sure. I getting undefined static methods in UserModel object in `user.model.js` file if I use the destructuring

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t show all my service files, as there are many

Comment: Only show those parts that are necessary to reproduce the problem - a [mcve].